# Как сделать адаптивное оформления виджета под разные экраны

Tags: android, android-widgets

На разных устройствах разные разрешения, сетки под виджеты, соотношения сторон виджета и пр. Как сделать адаптивное оформление виджета?
 Обычный виджет с картинкой и кнопкой, на картинке выводятся некие данные...
Или хотя бы как разместить `TextView`, что бы он был квадратным, но чтобы занимал всю ширину, в dp не получается т.к. на экранах с большим разрешением он получается мелким, а с маленьким - вытянутым...

Comment: Занимал всю ширину? Тоесть вы хотите чтобы `TextView` был на всю ширину экрана?

Comment: Отмасштабировать  виджет в виде квадрата средствами только разметки не представляется возможным. Вам нужно указать для него ширину `match_parent` (занимать весь родительский контейнер), затем получать программно это значение и устанавливать программно высоту по полученному параметру или , если таких виджетов будет несколько, имеет смысл сделать кастомное `View` унаследованное от `TextView`, который бы всегда устанавливал высоту, равную ширине (как [пример](https://github.com/chiuki/android-square-view/blob/master/src/com/sqisland/android/square_view/SquareView.java))